# Do I need a visa for Paris for a 8 hour transit?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, france, dominican-citizens

I am a Dominican Republic citizen, travelling from the Dominican Republic to Cairo via Paris. My connection time is 8 hours, do I need a transit visa?